# Cannot Create Virtual Device in Android Studio, HAXM is out-of-date

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, haxm

I need to create a virtual device for checking an app I'm developing. But nothing is working, I cannot create a virtual device from android studio. My processor is **Intel Pentium G4560 dual core** and I'm using **Windows 10 Home**. I downloaded the HAXM from github and manually installed it. But the new problem is- HAXM is out-of-date. But the latest version is 7.8.0 which I installed. The problem-

[image: While Creating Virtual Device]
[image: While Running the Virtual Device]

I enabled Intel Virtualization Technology from BIOS, I couldn't find Hyper-V so I used this line in CMD-`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` After this, I installed HAXM manually and checked if it is running or not and it is actually running as you can see-

[image: HAXM running]

Then what's the problem here? Why is it not running? I searched for the answer here and I did all I could, but it's still not running. It would be impossible to show my project if the virtual device is not running.

Answer (score 0):

for other users who might encounter a similar problem, you can try uninstalling HAXM from the control panel and then reinstall it from Android Studio.